# What is the difference between rgb() and rgba() opacity?

Tags: css, rgb, rgba

I found another question on SO about rgb vs rgba that is very similar, but it's missing an answer about the usage of **rgb with opacity**.

I know the difference between both – rgba is just rgb but with alpha for opacity. The thing is, it has been months or even years that I am using rgb with opacity values. It has always worked for me. `rgb(255, 0, 255, 0.5)`

Makes me wonder if there's an advantage to use one if both works the same? rgb has been there longer so browser compatibility I suppose is better? Also I was told by a coworker that rgba value will only work for background colors, but then again, I did some tests in codepen and it works on Edge and Chrome.

*(I know both are Chrome based both these are the one I have downloaded)*

Related question : [What are differences between RGB vs RGBA other than 'opacity'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538501/what-are-differences-between-rgb-vs-rgba-other-than-opacity)

---

### Here is my snippet

```css
/* texts */
.one {
  color: rgba(255, 200, 0, .5);
}
.oneFive {
  color: rgb(255, 200, 0, .5);
}

/* backgrounds */
.two {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
.three {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}



/*          */
/* settings */
/*          */
.two, .three {
  height: 50px;
}
.two {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.two, .three, .zero {
  color: white;
}
.one, .oneFive {
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
body { 
  background-color: #444; 
  color: white; 
}
.zero {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
dark grey 100% opacity

<div class="zero">dark green 100% opacity</div>

<div class="oneFive">rgb yellow text 70% opacity</div>
<div class="one">rgba yellow text 70% opacity</div>

<div class="two">rgb 50% background opacity</div>
<div class="three">rgba 50% background opacity</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's the browser translating what is essentially an incorrect value set in `rgb` with an opacity value. If you look in the browser dev tools under the computed tab, you'll notice that the `rgb` values are computed to `rgba`. I'm thinking that any browser that supports CSS3 will "fix" the property. _Also I was told by a coworker that rgba value will only work for background colors_ Your coworker is wrong.

Comment: _rgb has been there longer so browser compatibility I suppose is better?_ I wouldn't say that. You'll never notice a performance hit, but you'll make your browser do less work if it doesn't have to "fix" your incorrect values being passed to the `rgb` set.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb_colors

Comment: @disinfor Thanks for answering so quickly. I have indeed checked the console for the rgb value. It seems like Chrome does not need to fix it. (https://www.screencast.com/t/8essnzkacA). I see that rgba is an alias for rgb since CSS Level 4. I guess most popular browsers do. If you can bundle your replies as an answer, I would accept it as it gives me the information I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I think that the RGBA is used for saving adding another CSS property of opacity. If we want to add any element a color with opacity or background with opacity, rgba will be the best choice because we wouldn't write opacity property. So saving one line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer as requested:

I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's the browser translating what is essentially an "incorrect" value set in `rgb` with an opacity value.

If you look in the browser dev tools under the computed tab, you'll notice that the `rgb` values are computed to `rgba` (at least in Firefox).

I'm thinking that any browser that supports CSS3 will "fix" the property.

Also *I was told by a coworker that rgba value will only work for background colors*: Your coworker is wrong.

*`rgb` has been there longer so browser compatibility I suppose is better?* I wouldn't say that. You'll never notice a performance hit, but you'll make your browser do less work if it doesn't have to "fix" your incorrect values being passed to the `rgb` set. **Update**: `rgba` is an alias for `rgb`, so it's really not *fixing* anything, it's simply passing to `rgb` anyway.

Here is some documentation on `rgb` and `rgba` - specifically the aliasing of the functions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb_colors

Answer (score 1):

> Makes me wonder if there's an advantage to use one if both works the same?

It's not about advantage but this is something new defined in [the Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/)

> rgb() and rgba(), and hsl() and hsla() are now aliases of each other (all of them have an optional alpha). <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#changes-from-3)</sup>

And

> Also for legacy reasons, an rgba() function also exists, with an identical grammar and behavior to rgb(). <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#rgb-functions)</sup>

So `rgba()` is meant to disappear and only `rgb()` should be used but this won't happen because it will create a lot of issues and conflit so `rgba()` will still be considered and will simply have the same syntax as `rgb()`

Also note that the new syntax no more contain comma:

```
rgb() = rgb( <percentage>{3} [ / <alpha-value> ]? ) |
  rgb( <number>{3} [ / <alpha-value> ]? )
<alpha-value> = <number> | <percentage>
```

You should write `rgb(255 65 40)` or `rgb(255 65 40 / 80%)`  for example but still for legacy reasons the comma syntax is still supported:

> For legacy reasons, rgb() also supports an alternate syntax that separates all of its arguments with commas: